# How to send notifications from GAE to all the logged in users?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firebase, notifications

Our web app is hosted on two GAE servers, one for frontend and one for backend.

We have used angular2 for building the frontend and flask web framework for building the backend. Actually we have to implement a task of sending notification to all the logged in web users whenever a db record was inserted.

We all know that we can't send notifications directly from GAE since the development team going to depreciate Channel API. For this case, I have a thought of inserting some values into a firebase db (an firebase app created separately for handling notifications. Whenever a user logged in, through the returned user_key , the client has to create a seperate channel with the firebase server and listens for any messages) which further send notifications to all the logged in users or particular logged in user . And this part of logic should be written inside  [`_post_put_hook`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model__post_put_hook) .

Is this the correct way of doing the notification logic? I'm willing to hear your suggestions.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-firebase-real-time-events-app-engine) on migrating from channels to Firebase?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I haven't used Channel API before.. Can I follow the above doc to achieve my task? I provides an option for integrating Google project, so I'm gonna integrate my frontend GAE app. But I'm wondering that this app should contain a separate firebase db..